# Why does debug appear in the package.json file?

Tags: package.json

I just `npm init` in an empty folder that didn't do anything, but Debug is floating as shown in the picture.

[image: img_floating]

Why is this floating?

Does this interfere with the error?
If it interferes, is there any way to get rid of it?

I would really appreciate it if you let me know.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an error and the "debug" text is not actually part of the file.

VSCode inserts the "debug" button as a shortcut for running the scripts in the package.json file. When you click on it, a popup will appear allowing you to select the script you want to run or debug.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, he said it's stupid. Thank you for your reply!!

Comment: I would like it if the name was "Run", but I do not want the word "Debug" in my files. So I disable it in the settings (search for `npmScripts`).